# Domain(s?) of a Function

Tags: functions

Background:
I was transforming parametric equations into rectangular form for class, where I needed to state any domain restrictions for the rectangular form. I had some rectangular equation, $x(y)$, where I remember stating a restriction like $x>0$ or something. However, that got me thinking whether that was an actual *domain* restriction. I rewrote the restriction into terms of $y$, thinking the domain is the values the *input* to the function is allowed to be.

Question:
What is the technical definition of the domain of a function? For a function with multiple inputs, $f(x,y)$, are there two domains and one range? For a relation with multiple inputs and outputs (if that somehow exists), how would one define the domain(s) and range(s)? (Is that even a valid or useful question?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function always has a unique domain.

If your function has two numbers as inputs, that simply means that your domain is a set whose elements are ordered pairs of real number. I.e., the domain is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

In a similar way, if a function "multiple" outputs, let's say two real numbers, then your range is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

For example, a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ takes an ordered triple $(x,y,z)$ of real numbers as input and returns an ordered pair $(u,v)$ as outputs.

Is always good to remember that the domain and codomain of a function need *not* to be numerical sets.